# Receiver reloads when connecting from Chrome on Android

Tags: google-cast

I'm trying to make a custom receiver, a multi-player, Cast game. I'm also writing the sender app to run in the browser.

The problem I'm running into is that I can't connect to an already running receiver via chrome on Android. If I launch the receiver from an android device, I can connect to that receiver session from a desktop browser. However, if I launch the receiver from a desktop browser and try to connect from an android browser, the receiver is restarted. The same happens if I launch the receiver from one android browser and attempt to connect to it from a different android device.

Both sender and receiver are written with Angular, using the CAF framework.

--Edit--

Here's some logs, I stripped off the "cast_receiver_framework.js:77" from the beginning of every line.

This first one shows launching the receiver from Chrome on Android, then connecting from a desktop browser.

```
[  0.043s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Version: 2.0.0.0060
vendor.js:45467 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
[  9.301s] [cast.framework.common.libraryloader] library(//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js) is loaded
[  9.426s] [cast.framework.common.libraryloader] library(//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/2.3.5/shaka-player.compiled.js) is loaded
[  9.527s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"applicationId\":\"880C031C\",\"applicationName\":\"The Game\",\"closedCaption\":{},\"deviceCapabilities\":{\"bluetooth_supported\":false,\"display_supported\":true,\"focus_state_supported\":true,\"hi_res_audio_supported\":false},\"launchingSenderId\":\"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\",\"sessionId\":\"b2258c08-bada-4b4e-adc0-275a7b338e70\",\"type\":\"ready\",\"version\":\"1.29.104827\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[  9.540s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[  9.546s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager system ready event
[  9.555s] [cast.framework.Application] onReady
[  9.577s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"level\":1.0,\"muted\":false,\"type\":\"volumechanged\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[  9.581s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[  9.585s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching system volume changed event [1, false]
[  9.589s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"visibilitychanged\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[  9.590s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[  9.595s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Ignoring visibility changed event, state is already null
[  9.597s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"standbychanged\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[  9.601s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[  9.604s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"hdrType\":\"sdr\",\"type\":\"hdroutputtypechanged\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[  9.606s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[  9.613s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
[  9.629s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[],\"requestId\":0}"}
[  9.637s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"state\":\"IN_FOCUS\",\"type\":\"FOCUS_STATE\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.cac","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[  9.644s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[  9.662s] [cast.framework.common.EventHandler] onEvent for FOCUS_STATE
[  9.667s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"senderId\":\"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839\",\"type\":\"senderconnected\",\"userAgent\":\"Android CastSDK,12529050,Pixel 2,walleye,8.1.0\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[  9.673s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[  9.679s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager sender connected event [68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839]
[  9.685s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.debugoverlay, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839]
[  9.687s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.cac, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839]
[  9.688s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.broadcast, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839]
[  9.692s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839]
[  9.693s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.inject, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839]
[  9.695s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"requestId\":1,\"type\":\"GET_STATUS\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839"}
[  9.700s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[  9.718s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received
[  9.724s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager getStatus event
[  9.726s] [cast.framework.common.EventHandler] onEvent for getstatus
[  9.731s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus
[  9.740s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus: {"requestId":1}
[  9.742s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending status message to 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839
[  9.745s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.14:com.android.chrome-7839","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[],\"requestId\":1}"}
[ 27.436s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"requestId\":1,\"type\":\"GET_STATUS\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.16:com.google.android.gms-7840"}
[ 27.437s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 27.438s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received
[ 27.439s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager getStatus event
[ 27.439s] [cast.framework.common.EventHandler] onEvent for getstatus
[ 27.440s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus
[ 27.441s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus: {"requestId":1}
[ 27.441s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending status message to 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.16:com.google.android.gms-7840
[ 27.442s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.16:com.google.android.gms-7840","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[],\"requestId\":1}"}
[ 49.809s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"GET_STATUS\",\"requestId\":401804041}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty"}
[ 49.814s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 49.820s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received
[ 49.825s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager getStatus event
[ 49.830s] [cast.framework.common.EventHandler] onEvent for getstatus
[ 49.837s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus
[ 49.842s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus: {"requestId":401804041}
[ 49.847s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending status message to 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty
[ 49.852s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[],\"requestId\":401804041}"}
[ 51.151s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"senderId\":\"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545\",\"type\":\"senderconnected\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[ 51.157s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 51.162s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager sender connected event [68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 51.167s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.debugoverlay, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 51.174s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.cac, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 51.179s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.broadcast, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 51.184s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 51.189s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.inject, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 51.194s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"GET_STATUS\",\"requestId\":401804042}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty"}
[ 51.199s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 51.204s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received
[ 51.209s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager getStatus event
[ 51.214s] [cast.framework.common.EventHandler] onEvent for getstatus
[ 51.219s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus
[ 51.225s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus: {"requestId":401804042}
[ 51.229s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending status message to 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty
[ 51.234s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[],\"requestId\":401804042}"}
```

And this log shows launching the receiver from desktop first, then trying to connect to if with an android browser. There's no error when the android browser attempts to connect, just "Dispatching shutdown event".

```
[  0.049s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Version: 2.0.0.0060
vendor.js:45467 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
[ 11.726s] [cast.framework.common.libraryloader] library(//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/1.0.0/media_player.js) is loaded
[ 11.861s] [cast.framework.common.libraryloader] library(//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/2.3.5/shaka-player.compiled.js) is loaded
[ 11.921s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"applicationId\":\"880C031C\",\"applicationName\":\"The Game\",\"closedCaption\":{},\"deviceCapabilities\":{\"bluetooth_supported\":false,\"display_supported\":true,\"focus_state_supported\":true,\"hi_res_audio_supported\":false},\"launchingSenderId\":\"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\",\"sessionId\":\"a3b50537-b0d1-413f-9638-aab10b105253\",\"type\":\"ready\",\"version\":\"1.29.104827\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[ 11.936s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 11.949s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager system ready event
[ 11.955s] [cast.framework.Application] onReady
[ 11.974s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"level\":1.0,\"muted\":false,\"type\":\"volumechanged\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[ 11.978s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 11.984s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching system volume changed event [1, false]
[ 11.990s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"visibilitychanged\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[ 11.994s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 12.000s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Ignoring visibility changed event, state is already null
[ 12.005s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"standbychanged\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[ 12.010s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 12.015s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"hdrType\":\"sdr\",\"type\":\"hdroutputtypechanged\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[ 12.019s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 12.026s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
[ 12.037s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[],\"requestId\":0}"}
[ 12.048s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"state\":\"IN_FOCUS\",\"type\":\"FOCUS_STATE\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.cac","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[ 12.053s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 12.059s] [cast.framework.common.EventHandler] onEvent for FOCUS_STATE
[ 12.068s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"senderId\":\"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545\",\"type\":\"senderconnected\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
[ 12.073s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 12.080s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager sender connected event [68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 12.086s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.debugoverlay, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 12.092s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.cac, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 12.097s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.broadcast, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 12.102s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 12.107s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.inject, 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:152574013695890545]
[ 12.114s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"GET_STATUS\",\"requestId\":401804049}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty"}
[ 12.118s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
[ 12.130s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received
[ 12.135s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager getStatus event
[ 12.141s] [cast.framework.common.EventHandler] onEvent for getstatus
[ 12.148s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus
[ 12.153s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] onGetStatus: {"requestId":401804049}
[ 12.158s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending status message to 68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty
[ 12.165s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"68137637-265f-7e53-098b-043b5891b89e.10:sender-h2j2ft55n4ty","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[],\"requestId\":401804049}"}
[ 16.458s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching shutdown event
```

Comment: Could you provide the error logs? You may check this [Debugging documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging) on how to debug a Cast application.

Comment: Done. Unfortunately there's not a whole lot of use in them. There's no crash of any kind when the Android browser connects, just a shutdown event.

Comment: Please file an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc